# Finding the vertex of $y = x^2 - 6x + 1$. My solution doesn't match the book.

Tags: quadratics, conic-sections

I'm studying on how to find the vertex of a Parabola and got stuck with this question.

> Determine the vertex of $y = x^2 - 6x + 1$

I found the vertex is $V=(3,-8)$ (see work below), but my workbook showed it as $V=(3,10)$. Unfortunately, it does not have a section where it shows how it got to that answer so I'm doubting if my understanding is incorrect. If I use online algebra calculators, it matches with mine but I just want to make sure that I understand how signs and the formula work.

---

Formula I used to look for the Vertex:
$$V=\left(-\frac{b}{2a} , \frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}\right)$$

My solution:

$$\begin{align}
x &=-\frac{-6}{2(1)} = -\frac{-6}{2} = -\frac{-3}{1} = 3 \\[6pt]
y &=\frac{4(1)(1)-(-6^2)}{4(1)} = \frac{4-36}{4} = \frac{-32}{4} = \frac{-8}{1}=-8
\end{align}$$

$$V=(3,-8)$$

What I think was done on the book:

$$\begin{align}
x &=-\frac{-6}{2(1)} = -\frac{-6}{2} = -\frac{-3}{1} = 3 \\[6pt]
y &=\frac{4(1)(1)-(-6^2)}{4(1)} = \frac{4-36}{4} = \frac{40}{4} = \frac{10}{1}=10
\end{align}$$

$$V=(3,10)$$

Is it correct that I should've added $4-36$ since they are both positive numbers or subtract it?

Any explanation is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The lesson here is **watch your signs.**  Especially when you are intending to provide answers for others.

Comment: Now or then you find typos in books. Take it easy :-)

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Your solution is correct. (Be careful not to write "$-6^2$" when you *mean* "$(-6)^2$", or someone reading your solution may get confused.) BTW: Your question is *exemplary*: showing your work step-by-step, explaining your source of confusion, verifying your work with online calculators, even attempting to read the mind of the author of the textbook solution. If only other first-time (or even some long-time) MSE-ers were so conscientious. :)

Comment: Thank you for all your comments and thank you, @Blue for formatting my post in a clearer manner. I do agree that I also made a mistake with writing -6^2. I'll take it easy with these workbooks :)

Comment: The explanation for the book's answer is likely even simpler:  the solver completed the square as $ \ y = (x^2 - 6x + 9) + 1 \ $ and then added $ \ 9 + 1 \ $ without having subtracted off the $ \ 9 \ $  that they inserted to maintain the "value" of the right side of the equation.  It is common for authors to hire students to write solutions to the exercises, but they certainly don't _check_ those answers themselves.  As a result, textbooks typically have about one in 200 to 400 answers in error, regardless of how late the edition is.  Your answer _is_ correct.

Answer (score 1):

$4-36$ is indeed $-32$. Whenever you have $a - b$ and $b > a$, you should interpret it as $a - b = -1 \cdot (b - a)$. So your calculation seems to be right. And yes, the vertex of the parabola is at $(3, -8)$, this can be verified by differentiating and setting $y' = 0$.

$y' = 2x - 6 = 0 \implies x = 3$ and then $y(x=3) = 3^2 - 6 \cdot 3 + 1 = 9 - 18 + 1 = -8$. Your method is correct, I just mentioned the differentiation method to confirm the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I was also looking for a way to find out how can I verify if my answer is correct and your differentiation method helped. I'll include this as another step whenever I'm solving problems like these to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Any general parabola can be written as $L_1^2=4AL_2$, if $L_1$ and $L_2$ are Eq. of non-parallel lines.

If $L_1$ and $L_2$ are perpendicular and $L_1$ and $L_2$ are normalized, life is simple. The length of latus rectum (LR) is 4A. The Eq. of axis of the parabola is $L_1=0$ Tangen at vertex is $L_1=0$. Vertex is found by solving $L_1=0$ and $L_2=0$. The Eq. of directrix is $L_2=-A$, Eq. of LR is $L_2=A$, the focus F come by solving $L_1=0$ & $L_2=A$.

So in your case $y=x^2-6x+1 \implies y+8= (x-3)^2$ Then $L_1=x-3, L_2=y+8, A=1/4$ The vertex is given by $L_1=0, L_2=0$ which is $x=3, y=-8$. the vertex is (3,-8)$.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, well, both you and the book got the same $x$ coordinate for the vertex: $x=3$. So let's substitute $x=3$ into $y=x^2-6x+1$ and see the $y$ coordinate. It comes out as $y=-8$, so your solution is right.

(This shows there isn't much value in remembering the formula $y=\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}$ - you can always just remember the formula for $x$ and then substitute $x$ into the original equality $y=ax^2+bx+c$ - the result will be the same.)

Comment: oh! I didn't think of doing it that way so thank you for the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do this is to take a derivative, solve for the minimum, this will give you, your x-value. The substituting that value back into the original equation we can get the y-value. For example here you have:
y=(x^2)-6x+1
derivative: y'=(2x-6)
Solving for x-value (solving for when y'=0) : 2x-6=0 -> x=3   <-X-value
Now that we have the x value we can use this value in our original equation
y=3^2 -6*3 +1 We find that y=-8
This gives us the coordinates for the vertex. This is probably the fastest approach here as taking the derivative of this function is pretty basic.. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).